# Concatenate two inputs in a single Database row

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add a country phone number prefix based on the country chosen. I want it saved with the phone number as the same column on the database. The best option would be to add another column for prefix (countryCode in my case) but I want them concatenated together. Since I lack some experience when it comes to PHP I'm struggling a bit.
This is my HTML. Any suggestions or instructions?

```
<div>
  <label for="countryCode" value="Country Code"/>
  <select name="countryCode">
  <option>Denmark (+45)</option>
  <option>Mauritius (+230)</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="phone" value="Phone"/>
  <input type="number" name="phone"/>
</div>
```

This is my migrations table

```
$table->string('phone')->nullable();
```

This is my fortify file:

```
Validator::make($input,['phone' => ['required', 'string'],])->validate();
$company = Model::firstOrCreate([]],['phone' => $input['phone'],]);
```

This is my model:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'phone',
    ];
```

This is part of a two step authentication. This is the first step. I removed most of the unnecessary code.

Comment: `'phone' => $input['countryCode'] . ' ' . $input['phone']`

Comment: Use ```.``` operator to concatenate strings. like 
 $input['countryCode'] . '  ' . $input['phone'].
 Also make sue your ```options``` in select has dedicated values.

Comment: Thank you guys it worked. I tried that before but I wasn't figuring it out. After your instructions I tried harder and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your code work, first in your html for the country selectors, add value so you can access them in the controller

```
<div>
  <label for="countryCode" value="Country Code"/>
  <select name="countryCode">
  <option value="+45">Denmark (+45)</option>
  <option value="+230">Mauritius (+230)</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="phone" value="Phone"/>
  <input type="number" name="phone"/>
</div>
```

After that you should validate both input field in the controller:

```
Validator::make($input,['phone'       => ['required', 'string'],
                        'countryCode' => ['required', 'string'] 
                ])->validate();
```

And finally in the controller you can concatenate the two input and store it in one field with the . operator:

```
$company = Model::firstOrCreate([]],['phone' => $input['countryCode'].$input['phone'],]);
```

If the above code does not work (I just copied it from the question) try this instead:

```
$company = Model::create(['phone' => $input['countryCode'].$input['phone']]);
```